# Explain "+gP command from gvim menu

Tags: vim

In Gvim, the command for paste in the menu is <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>

My understanding is that <kbd>"</kbd> indicates I'll be pasting from a specific register, <kbd>+</kbd> indicates the register (some sort of global shared register?  the clipboard?), and <kbd>P</kbd> is the paste command.

However, this leaves the <kbd>g</kbd> unexplained.  What does it do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See `:help gP`:

> Just like "P", but leave the cursor just after the new text. {not in Vi}

Comment: And how paste and keep the same position ? Or how can I go back to the last position after paste some text?

Comment: Place a mark before moving the cursor, move the cursor, paste, go back to your mark. Or simply hit `\`\`` after your paste.

Comment: complete unusable solution but thanks anyway for answering. If I'm typing and hit <C-r>x to paste its unusable. <C-r> should trigger some <ESC> before it then paste then enters in insert mode again.
Its common for me to paste the wrong register in the middle a sentence and I dont have any way to undo this type of error.